# Effective way to store sparse matrix with three dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have `matrix 15 by 15` and and `1000 different symbols` any of that can be on position on `matrix[i][j] ( 0 <= i <= 15, 0 <= j <= 15 )` randomly placed. I have to count for every row number of occasions every symbol on every row and based on positions on row I have to apply new calculations. I done this by holding `NSArray of 15 NSDictionary-ies` and in every dictionary key is symbol which is in current row and value is NSArray which holds only column indexes ( j ). For every new whole calculations I have clear all dictionaries and then iterate again. Is there any better way and effective way to do this ?
I am new to objective c and don't know if bit operations between `row_index & symbol` ( symbol -> key in dictionary is also int ) would help because then I would have only one dictionary but for every row I would have to pass through all keys.

Comment: Hmmm...  One dimension is easy, two a bit more difficult.  Hard to even conceive of three.  The best approach would depend a lot on how sparse the data is and whether it's widely scattered or "bunched" together.  What are the characteristics of your data?

Comment: maybe add a reverse lookup data structure? keep an array of each symbol used and associate each symbol with a list of coordinates where that symbol has been used.

Comment: Your current approach seems reasonable, although I would use an `NSIndexSet` in the dictionary rather than an `NSArray`.  It is hard to offer more advice without seeing the type of operations you need to perform, but it seems this approach makes it fairly easy to identify whether a symbol is in a row (In the dictionary or not), the number of times in the row (count of the index set) and the columns for the symbol (the indicies in the IndexSet)